# Can OneLogin's ruby-saml interact with identity providers using SAML 1.1?

Tags: saml, onelogin

I'm new to SAML and didn't see much in the docs related to different SAML versions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,

ruby-saml is compatible with SAML 2.0... but knowadays, what IdP is not able to support SAML 2.0?

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't yet know the idp. Is supporting SAML 1.1 something that could feasibly be added in the future with open source help? Or would that be too ambitious and/or not a good addition to the project.